# php script echo displays in console instead of text inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, wordpress

I have this php script:

```
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getuser', 'getuser');
add_action('wp_ajax_getuser', 'getuser');

 function getuser($str)
{
    global $wpdb;

    if(!wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST['_nonce'], 'ajax-nonce'))
    {
            die('Not authorised!');
    }

    $myoption =  get_option( 'fixformdata_options' );
    $myoptionValue = maybe_unserialize( $myoption );    

    $result2 = $wpdb->get_row
    (
        $wpdb->prepare
        (
            "SELECT * FROM {$myoptionValue[tablename]} WHERE personeelsNummer = %s", 1
        )
    );

    if($result2) 
    {
        echo  json_encode( $result2 );
    }
}
```

And this javascript file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery('#input_1_2').change(function()
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            dataType : 'json',
            _nonce : myAjax.ajaxurl,
            url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
            data : {action: 'getuser', value: this.value},
            succes: function(response){
                var parsed = JSON.parse(response);
                var arr = [];
                for(var x in parsed){ arr.push(parsed[x]);}
                jQuery('#input_1_3').val(arr[1]);
                jQuery('#input_1_4').val(arr[2]);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Purpose of the scripts:

When a text inputs change, use the value of this text input to display some database data in another text input.

Now I have 2 problems:

1. I can't get the value of the text input to the function *getuser()*
2. When I hardcode a value in the sql statement, I get the results, but they display in the console instead of using:

.

```
success: function(response){
                var parsed = JSON.parse(response);
                var arr = [];
                for(var x in parsed){ arr.push(parsed[x]);}
                jQuery('#input_1_3').val(arr[1]);
                jQuery('#input_1_4').val(arr[2]);
            }
```

How can I resolve this, I'm new in Wordpress and Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of your php `_nonce` should be inside data. You cant use `this.value` as `this` is the jQuery ajax function itself so Try:

```
jQuery('#input_1_2').change(function()
  $value = $(this).val();
  jQuery.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            dataType : 'json',
            url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
            data : {
                   action: 'getuser',
                   value: $value,
                   _nonce : myAjax.ajaxurl
                   },
            succes: function(response){
                var parsed = JSON.parse(response);
                var arr = [];
                for(var x in parsed){ arr.push(parsed[x]);}
                jQuery('#input_1_3').val(arr[1]);
                jQuery('#input_1_4').val(arr[2]);
            }
        });
     });
```

In the php you will find `value` in

```
$_POST['value'];
```

**Edit**

inside the php add

```
header('content-type:application/json');
```

before

```
echo  json_encode( $result2 );
```

on the js you shoud then **not** need

```
JSON.parse(response)
```

you shoud have the results in the array, ie:

```
response[0]
```

etc

Comment: Hi, now I can get the value to the php, thanks!
When i use _nonce, i get the 'Not authorised!' error, do I have to use _nonce? This was advice given to me but it doesn't work...
Also I still get my results in the console instead of in the text inputs

Comment: TBH I don't know what its for, i don't know wordpress, but i saw it in `$_REQUEST['_nonce']` which means it should be in the jQuery ajax data field.

Comment: Hm maybe if I explain it like this:
this line 'echo  json_encode( $result2 );' is returning the results to the console, instead of to the jquery function(response) part.

Comment: Doesn't work, even if I just use this:
succes: function(response){console.log('test');}, I get nothing in console so the succes part of ajax call isn't working. I'm trying to figure out where the mistake is.

Comment: Try adding an `error` handler to the `$.ajax` too.  See if you end up there instead and why.

Comment: Used complete instead of succes, its being called now, having other problems though, reporting back to here in a minute.

Comment: I'm using console.log(response) and I get this:
 Object { readyState=4, responseText="{"personeelsNummer":"1",...oonplaats":"Meerhout"}0", status=200, meer...}
When I use JSON.parse i'm getting a parse error.

Comment: `{ readyState=4, responseText="...` is the xmhttprequest request obgect. try adding a `.error` function and see if there is an error

Comment: There were other mistakes, like I forgot to add die() at the end of the php script, everything is working now! Thanks